# What are the rules for sending marmite and creams abroad?

Tags: uk, eu, mail

I want to send some marmite (in an unopened bottle), moisturiser cream and some hydro-cortisone cream to a friend travelling in Denmark? Are these prohibited for international postage?

The rules I have read just say "liquids" and "food" in the prohibited list which isn't very clear to me.

For example: I read https://www.parcelmonkey.co.uk/prohibited-items which is who I was going to post the parcel using. However that list is different from http://www.postoffice.co.uk/mail/international-what-can-i-send . The latter lists liquids over 1 litre and doesn't mention food at all as far as I can see.

Comment: From which country? Makes a difference, potentially.

Comment: I rather presumed it's the UK...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about international postage, not travel.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Before you do, could you suggest somewhere else to ask?

Comment: @MarkMayo From the UK.

Comment: @eleanora I'm not aware of any Stack Exchange site where your question would be on-topic. However, it seems to me that you've already answered your own question by consulting the Royal Mail's list of forbidden items. If your items are not listed as forbidden, they are allowed.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Please feel free to delete/erase/destroy the question as off topic.

Answer (score 4):

> What are the rules for sending marmite and creams abroad?

Let's deal with this question in general. There are are a number of different potential rules that come into play:

- The export rules of the initiating country.
- The rules the carrier you are using.
- The import rules of the receiving country.

In specifics, since you are sending items within the EU which are not banned anywhere and do not have excise duty, you are golden for export/import.

If you are using The Post Office then they will apply the Universal Postal Union (UPU) rules, if you are using an independent carrier then they will apply theirs. Your question mirrors a belief that there is a universal regulation for sending items internationally -- there isn't. The UPU binds normal post but every carrier is free to carry whatever they want (more interesting items often at a price you do not want to pay, however -- transporting spent nuclear fuel will cost a bit more than transporting coal).

Whether the company in question treats creams and (barely) edible shoeshine as liquid is perhaps easiest clarified by calling them and not waiting for someone to wander in here who happened to attempt to send these specific items by that courier.